# How should I build a VPS that will host multiple small Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps

Up until now, I've always built my VPS dedicated to running just a single application in multiple instances, mostly with Unicorn. That way I could set up the whole environment to fit perfectly for that one specific application and be happy with it.

But now I need to build a VPS, that will host multiple small Ruby applications. Some of them will be Rails and some Sinatra. They will have basically zero traffic (under 100 visits per day), which means I don't even need multiple instances of a single app.

I don't really have experience with other servers than unicorn + nginx, but what I think I need would look something like this.

```
request to app1, gets loaded into memory and serves the request
request to app2, gets loaded into memory and serves the request
request to app3, there is not enough free memory
app1 gets killed before the app3 is booted to serve the request
```

I know this isn't an exactly perfect scenario, but imagine having a 10 or 20 small apps on a single server, where each app gets 5 hits a day. They don't exactly need to be up and running at all times.

As far as I know, Heroku does this with their free tier, where Dynos get killed after some idle time, and then they get loaded back up when a request comes in. That's basically what I need to do on my own server.

Comment: Check out Passenger + Nginx - http://www.modrails.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Apache + [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). Passenger by default loads the application only when you need it, e.g. the first request will take a bit longer (actually as long as it takes to load your framework).

If the application is idle for some predefined time, it will be removed from memory.

Setup is very easy and adding new applications is just adding one line in your apache configuration.